# how do i set up a negative reg expression match to pull out all the other links

Tags: php, regex, url

Hi I have the following html and want to pull out all the other links that are not `http://dont-match.co.uk`  all the URLs to be matched are different all the ones not to be matched are the same hence I'm thinking along the lines of a negative match ie match all that are not `http://dont-match.co.uk`

```
<a href="http://match-this-url.com/">link text</a> some 
text <a href="http://match-this-diff-url.com/">link text</a> more 
text <a href="http://dont-match.co.uk/">link text</a> 
text <a href="http://match-this-different-url.com/">link text</a> 
text <a href="http://dont-match.co.uk/">link text</a>
```

This is what i have so far:

```
/(<a href="http:\/\/[dont-match.co.uk]\/[^\"]*">([\d\D]*?)<\/a>)/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead `(?!expression not to match)`:

```
preg_match_all('/(<a href="http:\/\/(?!dont-match\.co\.uk).*?\/[^"]*">(.*?)<\/a>)/', $str, $matches);
```

Comment: FYI, you can use other characters than `/` as the regex delimiter.  For example, `'~(<a href="http://(?!dont-match\.co\.uk).*?/[^"]*">(.*?)</a>)~'` works just as well, and now you don't have to escape the slashes in the regex.

Comment: Looks like this answer is wrong. See the follow up (duplicate) question by the OP: [how do i stop this reg exp matching all this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837313/how-do-i-stop-this-reg-exp-matching-all-this) (Not saying it's trivial, you might find this answer useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13994665/367456)

Comment: @netcoder, do you see some reasoning why the OP opened a second question that looks like duplicate later claiming your regex here does not work? Not saying that it doesn't work in context of this question here, I was just wondering about the coincidence of the duplicate question.

Comment: @hakre: The other Q contains a `rel` attribute on the `<a>` tag, and it's not part of this regex. (You know when we repeat to use DOM, that's what this is ;-)

Comment: Oh yes, was even answered. Too late for me. Thanks for the feedback and sorry for the interruption.